# php Session array not accumulating values

Tags: php

The `$page_id` is the current page number. I was expecting from the following code to accumulate page numbers that I could later get but it's showing the current page only. I want e.g. to get page 1 value from the array when I'm on page 2.

```
$_SESSION['pages'] = array();

array_push($_SESSION['pages'],$page_id);
if (is_array($_SESSION['pages']) ) {
    echo "<br /> This is array <br />";
    foreach ($_SESSION['pages'] as $value) {

        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you visit the page, the statement `$_SESSION['pages'] = array();` overrides the `'pages'` key with an empty new array, losing all your current data. Instead, you should check if this array already exists before overwriting it:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['pages'])) {
    $_SESSION['pages'] = array();
}
array_push($_SESSION['pages'], $page_id);
```